# Scroll to the top of an element when document is loaded

Tags: javascript

**Intention:** Automatically scroll the window to the top of a DOM element when the document is loaded.

---

**via JavaScript:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('foo').scrollIntoView(true);
};
```

**Questions and Concerns:**

- Is there a more compact and/or smarter technique?
- Does this technique pose issues or potential conflicts?
- With the above said, should it matter where on the document it's loaded? If so, what's the best location? I've already studied [this question and its references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document) closely and I'm led to believe it's best to have this kind of script located toward the bottom the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three concerns:

1. Error if there is not element called 'foo'
2. I have no idea what that boolean in the function is for.  Passing booleans at parameters is  very bad.  I have no idea what happens if I were to pass it false or any other value. Not scroll into view? I know that it is for topAlign but why not leave it out.
3. you can't use the `onload` event again without messing it up.

Comment: "If true, the scrolled element is aligned with the top of the scroll area. If false, it is aligned with the bottom." [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Comment: Obviously, the element won't be called 'foo' in production. Where would the second `onload` event be placed and why is it an improvement?

Comment: 'foo' by any other name.. is still 'foo'... you are chaining behavior when it could break your code.  I am recommending doing a bit of checking like: ` if (el = document.getElementById('foo')) el.scrollIntoView();

Comment: @gmeben it is topAligned by default... that is my point.

Comment: I feel adding a conditional to test for a single element that's known to exist is a bit overkill. Compactness is one of my goals. My concerns for potential conflict comes down to whether or not `scrollIntoView` or the way I'm initializing the script is known to cause behavior issues, and if so, is there an alternative method?

Comment: I should've known that I could strip out the boolean value being passed to make this more compact. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Still, I'd be interested to see how `onload` could be used again for this script. Unless you meant that `onload` could be used again _elsewhere_ in the document without worrying about conflict.

Comment: @gmeben apologies I meant "you can't use the onload event again without messing it up."

Comment: @gmeben I can see how the conditional test can seem overkill.  Just a concern for me.

Comment: That's what I figured. Excellent

Comment: If I were applying this to an array of DOM elements, then I could definitely see the conditional being a practical and thing to implement and worthy of sacrificing a bit of the conciseness of the script.

Comment: Also, I edited your post to show the final answer for people who show up here in the future, but it won't be shown until it's 'peer reviewed,' whatever that means...